# Where is the place to report bugs and make suggestions about Elementary Document Viewer (Evince)

Tags: release-loki

I would like to report a bug that is present on the Loki Document Viewer.

What is the best place to report and make suggestions about this packages?

I tried the Elementary's github, but i couldn't find the Document Viewer section.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this page helps: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/ReportingBugs
Seems like it's a Gnome project.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your reply.  I think that Elementary changes the Evince to fit the Elementary style.  One of the issues that i have is that when Evince is in fullscreen the tool bar have an auto-hide feature, but not only this is not present on other Ubuntu distros, but the animation and style doesn't look good.